# Question about a subset in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(p,q)$

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Would the set of Hermitian matrices inside the Lie algebra $$\mathfrak{u}(p,q):= \{X\in \mathbf{M}_n(\mathbb{C}): X^{*}I_{p,q}= -I_{p,q}X\},$$ form a Lie subalgebra? Are there any good references pertaining to these indefinite unitary Lie algebras that could answer this question?

Comment: What is $I_{p,q}$? (I guess the matrix having $p$ pieces of $+1$ and $q$ pieces of $-1$ in the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere.) Is $p+q=n$ assumed?

Comment: Note also that  $X^*=X$ and $Y^*=Y$ implies $[X,Y]^*=(XY-YX)^*=Y^*X^*-X^*Y^*=YX-XY=-[X,Y]$. So, your subset of Hermitians is closed under $[,]$ iff all of them commute with each other.

Comment: You are correct about $I_{p,q}$.